# Where can I download jQueryMobile themes

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, styles, themes

jQueryMobile default themes are okay, and I know we can change ourselves using the theme roller. But is there a place I can download customized themes from a list/library?

I don't like the 18x18 px micro images on the header-bar and would like more open and bold icons. Also the icons should work well on high-res screens.

If the swatches and themes are good, can buy as well, but if there are good ones on github, great!

For example, this is good: http://taitems.github.com/iOS-Inspired-jQuery-Mobile-Theme/

Some more examples:

https://github.com/jjoe64/jquery-mobile-android-theme
http://www.andymatthews.net/read/2012/02/13/New-jQuery-Mobile-theme:-Twitter-Bootstrap

Thank you.

M

Comment: There is currently no repository for jQuery Mobile themes. You will have to search them out on your own. I mostly see icon packs associated with jQuery Mobile rather than whole themes.

Answer (score 8):

There's a new theme generator called Graphite For jQuery Mobile 1.3.1.  You can see it here:

[Graphite - A Theme Pack & Generator For jQuery Mobile](http://driftyco.github.io/graphite/)

Comment: Mentioned link is dead.

Answer (score 5):

I like this one:

http://nativedroid.godesign.ch/

you can customize it easy.

Answer (score 1):

Created my own, here's a link to it...

http://jquerymobile.com/themeroller/?ver=1.1.0&style_id=20120622-116

Cheers,

M

Answer (score 0):

Well you can always roll your own

- http://jquerymobile.com/themeroller/

Search Google I found these but not sure of good they are

- http://www.jquery4u.com/mobile/10-free-jquery-mobile-themes/

Comment: These are not based on the new theme-roller framework and pretty old... I added two other themes out there ...